# How is browser's debugger different from Angular's setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, dom-events

I am working on an angular app which is embedded in an application I don't have access to. I am using a router to move from page to page once a pop-up modal has been OK'd (checkbox & button). I have to ensure that the modal has been destroyed before moving to the next page or the outer page causes problems. I have tried using `*ngif="destroyModal"`. It works, but it's not happening in-time.

When I set the browser's debugger to stop the action on line with `this.myRequestService.update...` it seems to stop the action in such a way that my modal destroy works. If I use a debugger break-point on the next line (in the called-method) it doesn't work.

```js
public goToPageTwo(): void {
    this.myObject = {};

    this.myRequestService.updateNextPg(this.myObject).subscribe((nextPageResponse) => {
        this.nextPageService.setData(nextPageResponse);
        this.router.navigateByUrl(NEXT_PAGE);
    }
}
```

I have tried several approaches with `setTimeout(() => this.router.navigateByUrl(NEXT_PAGE), 2000)` but this doesn't seem to have any effect. The only stop that allows the modal destroy to happen is one delivered by a debugger break-point.

I can't ask the user to do this :(

Comment: I think your setTimeout has a spelling mistake in it. navidageByUrl isn't the same navigateByUrl. Is this simply a spelling mistake?

Comment: Sorry, typo in the copy from work laptop, fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: What modal component are you using? Some of them expose an "onclosed" event you can listen for. Some even expose an observable or promise you can latch onto.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the page navigation in the [ngOnDestroy()](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy) life cycle event.

```js
myClass {
  ...
  ngOnDestroy(){
    //do it here
  }
}
```

This would be where you would want to cause the page navigation when the component is closed and cleaned up.

Comment: This answer did not solve my particular problem, where the setTimeout was differing from the browser break-point, but it was certainly another valid option to try. Thanks!